# Историческое правописание императивов

Tags: этимология

Каково историческое правописание императивов, образованных от одногласных глаголов на и/ы:

*бить;
лить;
мыть;
ныть;
пить;
рыть;
шить;
крыть.*

Чем был вызван переход к современному правописанию?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про императивы, а приводите примеры инфинитивов.

Answer (score 1):

Ранее, при образовании императивов от одногласных глаголов на и/ы, отсутствовало чередование гласных и/е, ы/о.

То есть:

б**и**и -> б**е**й;
л**и**и -> л**е**й;
п**и**и -> п**е**й;
м**ы**и -> м**о**й;
н**ы**и -> н**о**й;
р**ы**и -> р**о**й
ш**и**и -> ш**е**й;
кр**ы**и -> кр**о**й.

Comment: Старые формы без чередования сохранились в малороссийских диалектах. Скажем, вместо "стой" там до сих пор говорят "стій".